# Measure: Return the most recent value that is not blank

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg6OK.png)

I was wondering if someone could help me creating a measure for the following scenario.

Purpose: Capturing the most recent "Work ratio" that is not blank. Both "Effective Date" and "Work Ratio" are in the same table "Employment".

I have played with a few formulas but it doesn't seem to return the expected value.

In this case, I would expect the measure to return 0.60

Thanks for any help,

NBK Current Work Ratio (FT) =
var m = CALCULATE(MAX(Employment[Effective Date]),Employment[Work Ratio] <> BLANK() )
return
CALCULATE(MAX(Employment[Work Ratio]),Employment[Effective Date] = m)

I am getting unexpected results, not sure how it is currently filtering.

Comment: Are you expecting 0.6 for the April 1, 2023 row? What values are you getting? If your `Employment` table is in the right order, then you could use `LASTNONBLANK(Employment[Work Ratio], 1)` or `FIRSTNONBLANK`